# Windows 10 install hangs with blue logo

Tags: windows, installation, windows-10, windows-installation, windows-installer

I'm trying to do a clean install from a Microsoft Windows 10 DVD. The blue windows logo appears on black background, and it remains there. Nothing else happens. What can I do to fix this?

Motherboard: Gigabyte EP35-DS3L
Memory: 4GB RAM
Processor: Intel Core 2 CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz (2 CPUs)
HDD: 465 GB

The computer was previously running Windows Vista.

Comment: Does the logo appear when you're booting into the install DVD?  Or after the first round of installing and when you're booting into the new operating system to finish the install?

Comment: @LevenTech Booting into the install DVD.

Answer (score 0):

A guess is that the processor doesn't support *PrefetchW* which seems to be listed in the requirements for Windows 10 x64 on Wikipedia:

> x86-64 CPUs must also support CMPXCHG16B, PrefetchW and LAHF/SAHF instructions.

PrefetchW in turn seems to be a part of 3DNow! which is [not listed for that processor](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Duo%20E8400%20EU80570PJ0806M%20-%20AT80570PJ0806M%20(BX80570E8400).html).